# Mysql and c# updating

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I currently have a mysql data table that fills up when people complete a form.  I then have my visual studio c# bot pull this data and do what I want.  The table numbers the table using integers that increase by 1 each time.  My bot looks in the table for id 1 and adds it.

The problem I have is that once my bot completes what someone wants and deletes the data, it does not recognize to go onto the next one since that id is not 1 and something else, like 2.  I tried to have my c# bot add 1 to a variable each time and then have that variable represent the id so that every time the bot completed something it would go onto the next id.  The problem with this was that every time the bot completed with one person the variable was reset back to 1.  I am stuck now and can't figure out what to do.  Any help would be great.

This is currently the string I use "select name from names where id = 1".  If I can somehow instead of having the id = 1 and have it look for the next lowest id in my table then that would work.

Edit: Actually I think I figured out how to have the last added id be used.  I will post it if I find it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very confused by your wording... it seems like you're saying you have a table filled with form requests that are auto-numbered and then you have a bot that fulfills this requests by looking for the request with id=1 and then deletes that record when the request is complete. If that's correct then that's not the right way to go about this. You should just skip the identifier entirely and have the bot query using "SELECT TOP 1", so that it always selects the first/oldest request. However, keep a unique id in your table as a key for quicker queries, though. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, if you want the lowest ID then you could do something like this:

```
 SELECT 
     Name 
 FROM 
     Names 
 ORDER BY ID
 Limit 1
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yup.  Thanks.  I had something like this before but I didn't put the limit.  Thanks a bunch.